# Can a representation of Matrix Lie Groups be understood as an embedding?

Tags: representation-theory, manifolds, lie-groups

A representation is a homomorphism
$$  \Pi: G \rightarrow GL(V)$$
$GL(V)$ is a matrix Lie group and we could regard it as $\mathbb{C}^{N^2}$ if $V$ is a $N-$dimensional complex vector space. So the question is if we could say that a representation of $G$ is an embedding of $G$ in $GL(V)$

Comment: Not for non-faithful reps.

Comment: @user10354138 ups... i forgot that part, of course it needs to be faithful. So then it can be understood in that way? I find it a really nice and intuitively way of seeing representations

Comment: A faithful rep need not be an embedding if $G$ is not compact. Consider the map $\mathbb{R} \to Gl_2(\mathbb{C})$ by $t\mapsto \mathrm{diag}(e^{it}, e^{i\alpha t})$ for some $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ irrational.